# Render NumPy array in FastAPI

Tags: python, numpy, fastapi, bytesio

I have found [How to return a numpy array as an image using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903231/return-numpy-array-as-image-from-fastapi), however, I am still struggling to show the image, which appears just as a white square.

I read an array into `io.BytesIO` like so:

```
def iterarray(array):
    output = io.BytesIO()
    np.savez(output, array)
    yield output.get_value()
```

In my endpoint, my return is `StreamingResponse(iterarray(), media_type='application/octet-stream')`

When I leave the `media_type` blank to be inferred a zipfile is downloaded.

How do I get the array to be displayed as an image?

Comment: How are you reading the file after you download it?

Comment: @richardec  I'm generating the array by finding the mean of a set of arrays (which come from grib files)  so I'm not really downloading a file? Could you please clarify if I've misunderstood

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. You have a `fastapi` server, right? and you're returning an array from it, so how are you getting that array on the other end?

Comment: oh i see, they are local files on my computer and I have just hardcoded paths to them within my code. They get read using the GDAL library to extract the array

Comment: So, if you're getting a white image, the arrays must be being loaded incorrectly. Can you peek in and see what the array is after loading it?

Comment: A large proportion of the array is 0 (image border) and the image itself is quite small compared to this so I guess i need to "crop" the array to remove the 0s from the outside

Comment: `application/octet-stream` isn't a valid image type - i.e. the response shouldn't be parsed or processed as an image. `npz` files which `savez` generates aren't valid image files that regular browsers can parse. You can usually use Pillow/PIL to convert a set of binary data to a valid image format.

Comment: thank you @MatsLindh , your suggestion fixed my problem. Happy to accept as correct if you wish to submit as an answer

Comment: @Chris Thanks for your very comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Option 1 - Return image as bytes

The below examples show how to convert an image loaded from disk, or an in-memory image (in the form of numpy array), into bytes (using either `PIL` or `OpenCV` libraries) and return them using a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response). For the purposes of this demo, the below code is used to create the in-memory sample image (numpy array), which is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659378/17865804).

```py
# Function to create a sample RGB image
def create_img():
    w, h = 512, 512
    arr = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    arr[0:256, 0:256] = [255, 0, 0] # red patch in upper left
    return arr
```

### Using PIL

##### Server side:

You can load an image from disk using `Image.open`, or use [`Image.fromarray`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray) to load an in-memory image (**Note**: For demo purposes, when the case is loading the image from disk, the below demonstrates that operation inside the route. However, if the same image is going to be served multiple times, one could load the image only once at `startup` and [store it on the `app` instance](https://www.starlette.io/applications/#accessing-the-app-instance), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71613757/17865804)). Next, write the image to a buffered stream, i.e., [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO), and use the [`getvalue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO.getvalue) method to get the entire contents of the buffer. Even though the buffered stream is garbage collected when goes out of scope, it is generally [better to call `close()` or use the `with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9719180), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646297/17865804) and below.

```py
from fastapi import Response
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import io

@app.get('/image', response_class=Response)
def get_image():
    # loading image from disk
    # im = Image.open('test.png')
    
    # using an in-memory image
    arr = create_img()
    im = Image.fromarray(arr)
    
    # save image to an in-memory bytes buffer
    with io.BytesIO() as buf:
        im.save(buf, format='PNG')
        im_bytes = buf.getvalue()
        
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="test.png"'}
    return Response(im_bytes, headers=headers, media_type='image/png')
```

##### Client side:

The below demonstrates how to send a request to the above endpoint using Python requests module, and write the received bytes to a file, or convert the bytes back into PIL `Image`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32908899/17865804).

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/image'
r = requests.get(url=url)

# write raw bytes to file
with open('test.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

# or, convert back to PIL Image
# im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(r.content))
# im.save('test.png')
```

### Using OpenCV

##### Server side:

You can load an image from disk using [`cv2.imread()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) function, or use an in-memory image, which—if it is in `RGB` order, as in the example below—needs to be converted, as [OpenCV uses `BGR` as its default colour order for images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42406781/17865804). Next, use [`cv2.imencode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga461f9ac09887e47797a54567df3b8b63) function, which compresses the image data (based on the file extension you pass that defines the output format, i.e., `.png`, `.jpg`, etc.) and stores it in an in-memory buffer that is used to transfer the data over the network.

```py
import cv2

@app.get('/image', response_class=Response)
def get_image():
    # loading image from disk
    # arr = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    # using an in-memory image
    arr = create_img()
    arr = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    # arr = cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA) # if dealing with 4-channel RGBA (transparent) image

    success, im = cv2.imencode('.png', arr)
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="test.png"'}
    return Response(im.tobytes() , headers=headers, media_type='image/png')
```

##### Client side:

On client side, you can write the raw bytes to a file, or use the [`numpy.frombuffer()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html#numpy-frombuffer) function and [`cv2.imdecode()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga26a67788faa58ade337f8d28ba0eb19e) function to decompress the buffer into an image format (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34475270/17865804))—`cv2.imdecode()` does not require a file extension, as the correct codec will be deduced from the first bytes of the compressed image in the buffer.

```py
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/image'
r = requests.get(url=url) 

# write raw bytes to file
with open('test.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

# or, convert back to image format    
# arr = np.frombuffer(r.content, np.uint8)
# img_np = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
# cv2.imwrite('test.png', img_np)
```

---

### Useful Information

Since you noted that you would like the image displayed similar to a [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse), using a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) to return the bytes should be the way to do this, instead of using [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse) (as shown in your question). To indicate that the image should be viewed in the browser, the `HTTP` response should include the following header, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11894771/17865804) and as shown in the above examples (the quotes around the `filename` are required, if the `filename` contains special characters):

```
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="test.png"'}
```

Whereas, to have the image downloaded rather than viewed (use `attachment` instead):

```
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="test.png"'}
```

If you would like to display (or download) the image using a JavaScript interface, such as Fetch API or Axios, have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71324775/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804).

As for the [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse), if the numpy array is fully loaded into memory from the beginning, `StreamingResponse` is not necessary at all. `StreamingResponse` streams by iterating over the chunks provided by your `iter()` function (if `Content-Length` is not set in the headers—unlike `StreamingResponse`, other `Response` classes set that header for you, so that the browser will know where the data ends). As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67497103/17865804):

> Chunked transfer encoding makes sense when you don't know the size of
> your output ahead of time, and you don't want to wait to collect it
> all to find out before you start sending it to the client. That can
> apply to stuff like serving the results of slow database queries, but
> it **doesn't generally apply to serving images**.

Even if you would like to stream an image file that is saved on disk (which you should rather not, unless it is a rather large file that can't fit into memory. Instead, you should use use [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse)), [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) objects, such as those created by `open()`, are normal iterators; thus, you can return them directly in a `StreamingResponse`, as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#using-streamingresponse-with-file-like-objects) and as shown below (if you find `yield from f` being rather slow when using `StreamingResponse`, please have a look at [this answer](https://www.starlette.io/applications/#accessing-the-app-instance) for solutions):

```py
@app.get('/image')
def get_image():
    def iterfile():  
        with open('test.png', mode='rb') as f:  
            yield from f  
            
    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), media_type='image/png')
```

or, if the image was loaded into memory instead, and was then saved into a [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) buffered stream in order to return the bytes, `BytesIO` is a [file-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object (like all the concrete classes of [io module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)), which means you could return it directly in a `StreamingResponse`:

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks

@app.get('/image')
def get_image(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    arr = create_img()
    im = Image.fromarray(arr)
    buf = BytesIO()
    im.save(buf, format='PNG')
    buf.seek(0)
    background_tasks.add_task(buf.close)
    return StreamingResponse(buf, media_type='image/png')
```

Thus, for your case scenario, it is best to return a [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) with your custom `content` and [`media_type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types), as well as setting the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header, as described above, so that the image is viewed in the browser.

## Option 2 - Return image as JSON-encoded numpy array

The below should not be used for displaying the image in the browser, but it is rather added here for the sake of completeness, showing how to convert an image into a numpy array (preferably, [using `asarray()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14415801)), then [return the data in JSON format,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) and finally, convert the data back to image on client side, as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71104203/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71265664/17865804) answer. For faster alternatives to the standard Python `json` library, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804).

### Using PIL

##### Server side:

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import json

@app.get('/image')
def get_image():
    im = Image.open('test.png')
    # im = Image.open('test.png').convert('RGBA') # if dealing with 4-channel RGBA (transparent) image 
    arr = np.asarray(im)
    return json.dumps(arr.tolist())
```

##### Client side:

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/image'
r = requests.get(url=url) 
arr = np.asarray(json.loads(r.json())).astype(np.uint8)
im = Image.fromarray(arr)
im.save('test_received.png')
```

### Using OpenCV

##### Server side:

```py
import cv2
import json

@app.get('/image')
def get_image():
    arr = cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    return json.dumps(arr.tolist())
```

##### Client side:

```py
import requests
import numpy as np
import cv2
import json

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/image'
r = requests.get(url=url) 
arr = np.asarray(json.loads(r.json())).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite('test_received.png', arr)
```